# Forced Serialization on SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019, parallelism

I ran Brent Ozar's BlitzCache and it identified a query that is executing with Forced Serialization. I'm assuming it is because of the Calendar functions contained with the query. I was looking for options to remedy it and learned that the Froid feature in SQL Server 2019 is supposed to prevent Forced Serialization from occurring. I have the database set to 2019 (150) compatibility. Is there a reason this query is not benefitting from Froid?

```
    select
      DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, MonthOfDate), 0) as Quarter
      ,[PartnerCD]
      ,[PartnerNM]
      ,[PartnerGRPNM]
      ,[CCOMemberID]
      ,[MemberID]
      ,[CCOType]
      ,[RateCD]
      ,[Rate]
      ,sum([MemberMonth]) as MemberQuarter
      ,[CurrentAge]
      ,[AgeAtTime] = CASE WHEN dbo.fn_CalculateAge(BirthDT, (DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, MonthOfDate), 0)), 'YEAR') < 0 THEN NULL ELSE dbo.fn_CalculateAge(BirthDT, (DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, MonthOfDate), 0)), 'YEAR') END
      ,AgeCategory = dbo.fn_CalculateAgeCatYrsOrdered(BirthDT, (DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, MonthOfDate), 0)))
      ,[BirthDT]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[Language]
      ,[RaceEthnicity]
      ,[ZipCD]
FROM [BIP].[QDS].[Enrollment_Monthly]  
group by DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, MonthOfDate), 0)
      ,[PartnerCD]
      ,[PartnerNM]
      ,[PartnerGRPNM]
      ,[CCOMemberID]
      ,[MemberID]
      ,[CCOType]
      ,[RateCD]
      ,[Rate]
      ,[CurrentAge]
      ,[BirthDT]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[Language]
      ,[RaceEthnicity]
      ,[ZipCD]
```

Query plan is available in case that is helpful.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1L0EMrdo

Comment: Have a look at the [scalar udf requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16#requirements), which may help you figure out why your function can't be inlined.

Comment: Cripes - that has more restrictions than a Groupon. Since the functions are calculating current age my query gets excluded because it uses GETDATE().

Comment: @Don Scalar UDFs are still not great in 2019. I wouldn't rely on them getting inclined (meaning they'll at best still be executed RBAR), and in general still recommend them being avoided.